# Tomar Variable JS y llevarla a PHP SIN JQUERY

Tags: php, javascript

*Quiero armar un sistema de experiencia para un juego. La idea en si es que dentro de esta función:

```
 function Experiencia(...parámetros para definir la exp final){
    return expC = 50;  
}
```

...se arme un proceso dependiendo de contra que se combatió se defina cuanta experiencia retorna.

*Ahora para poder actualizar la experiencia que ya tenia el jugador, necesito obtener ese valor de variable y mandarla mediante AJAX a un archivo "ActualizaStat.php" para que me haga un UPDATE en la base de datos MYSQL.

```
<button id="btnInfComb"> <a href="enviaDatosCombate.php">Aceptar</a></button>

function EnviaDatosCombate() {

    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest()
    xhr.open("POST","ActualizaStat.php",true)
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if(xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200){
           var a = Experiencia()
           //Aca dentro que tendria que hacer para poder mandar el valor en 
           //SEND
        }
    }

    xhr.send(a)
}
```

*Del lado de PHP en "ActualizaStat.php" tendría el siguiente fragmento de código.
(No hace falta decirme como realizar el update, solo muestro este fragmento para saber que lo llamo mediante POST..)

```
<?php
$datos = $_POST['a'];
echo $datos;
?>
```

Les agradecería muchísimo la ayuda como siempre.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El evento `xhr.onreadystatechange` se ejecuta una vez todo el proceso de envió y retorno de datos ha finalizado por lo cual ahí no enviarías ningún dato a tu php.

En tu **JS** podrías enviar los datos de esta forma:

```
<button id="btnInfComb" onclick="EnviaDatosCombate()">Acepta</button>

function Experiencia(){
    return expC = 50;  
}

function EnviaDatosCombate() {

    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("POST", "ActualizaStat.php", true);
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if(xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200){
           //Aca recibes los datos de vuelta en caso de que existan
        }
    }

    var exp = Experiencia();

    var datos = new FormData();
    datos.append('experiencia', exp);

    xhr.send(datos)
}
```

Y en tu **PHP** los recibes así:

```
<?php
    $datos = $_POST['experiencia'];
    echo $datos;
?>
```

Comment: Como va Camilo!
Sabes que me sale este error.
Undefined index: expexperiencia

Comment: @Alfacoy Uhh error mio de digitación, ya lo organizo, pero debes tener en cuenta que la forma en que lo vas a recibir es el nombre que le asignaste al momento de hacer el .append()

Comment: Seria experienciaexp ??

Comment: @Alfacoy nono, .append() recibe dos parámetros el primero es el key/nombre y el segundo es el valor, en este caso el nombre es experiencia y su valor es lo contenido en la variable exp..ya edité la respuesta

Comment: Sigue saliendo lo mismo, Undefined index: experiencia...

Hice tal cual copy paste por si las dudas escribí algo mal..

Comment: Con calma que igual no tengo apuro :)  aun así muchas gracias por la ayuda Camilo, me sacaste de todas vos ..

Comment: @Alfacoy te he editado la respuesta, vuelve aprobar ! :D

Comment: Sigue idéntico :( ... 

Probe tambien con 

 xhr.setRequestHeader('X-Requested-With', 'XMLHttpRequest');

Que es para trabajar con FormData... pero de igual forma sigue sin hacer el echo.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/70076/discussion-between-camilo-vasquez-and-alfacoy).

Comment: Quedo mas que solucionado... Muchas Gracias Camilo!